# Am i on the right path to figuring out this CASE statement

Tags: mysql

Create a query that returns the alphabetized first letter of the customer's last name and the count of active and inactive customers. Limit the results to only those first letters that occur in the last_name column of the customer table.

Label the columns as follows:

starts_with is the first column and the first letter of the customer's last_name.
active_count is the second column and the count of active customers (as defined in the textbook examples of Chapter 11).
inactive_count is the third column and the count of inactive customers (as defined in the textbook examples of Chapter 11).
The output should look like the following:
[The image shows the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqbFP.png)
This is using the sakila database and using CASE

so far i have gotten this far and im not sure i am doing the right thing at all. I have been working on this for 3 hours and im a little overwhelmed

SELECT
DISTINCT LEFT(last_name,1)
FROM customer
SUM(CASE WHEN last_name = 'A' THEN 1 END)
SUM(CASE WHEN last_name = 'B' THEN 1 END)

Comment: don't use distinct, you will want to use group by left(last_name,1).  and the from (and then  group by) go *after* the fields you select.  and you want the sum of active and inactive users; there's no need for a CASE last_name inside the sum, since the group by will make sum only apply to the correct table rows.